# How to create a Python editor in Angular 8

Tags: angular8, codemirror

Looking for an sample code in Angular 8 to edit Python code. I tried CodeMirror (https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons) but not able to add the python editor. Is there any plug-ins/option available to add python autocomplete ??